# Convert 3D STL(Single File) file 2D STL(Multiple file)

Tags: c#

I need to convert 3D STL(Single File) file 2D STL(Multiple file). I have tried with slice, slic3r,meshlab,netfabb smart basic edition.

Can i get any open source to get 2D slices from 3D stl file.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#, STL (stl = standard template library, not the 3D file format), or programming?

Comment: using C# or any other Programming. Not Standard Template Library. STL(STereoLithography) file.